# Automated download of directory structure from web page to flash drive

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, activex

I've created a product with an internal flash drive and I want to allow it to download a directory structure from my web site when inserted into a computer with minimal user interaction. My question is, what sort of technology can accomplish this?

Comment: I've done enough research to know I cant do it with javascript, and I just started reading up about activeX controls. Basically I need something that when the user logs into the "Update" part of my web page, something is run that scans their computer to detect if the product is plugged in, and if it is, downloads the said files and directory structure to it without involving the user with alot of dialog boxes. I want it to be simple enough my grandfather could do it. But I'm not sure what frameworks out there can accomplish this... So I'm not sure where to start researching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use windows embedded in your internal flash to have minimal windows OS
   with all mandatories binaries

   1. Use WebClient class to download your directory structure from your website file by file

      using System.Net;

      WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
      webClient.DownloadFile("http://mysite.com/myfile.txt", @"c:\myfile.txt");
   2. this could be a windows service (auto start) that check if directory exists if not it download your directory structure. Be carefull you have to detect the drive given by computer to make a local copy (F: or ...)